# How to merge sequential integer values into intervals in PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch

I have a 1D array:

```
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 20, 31, 32, 33, 34]
```

which I want to turn into a 2D interval array by merging every consecutive values into intervals:

```
[
  [ 3,  7],
  [20, 20],
  [32, 34]
]
```

What would be a decent, possibly GPU-friendly, way to do it?

Comment: Can you please tell, how the numbers 3,7,20,20,32,34 are selected?

Comment: numbers are coming from `tnsr.nonzero().flatten()`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is ideal, but you can try `cumsum()` on the differences compared to `1`. Then use that to slice the original data:

```
# mark the consecutive blocks
blocks = torch.cat([torch.tensor([0]),(t[1:] - t[:-1]) != 1]).cumsum(dim=0)

# where the blocks shift
mask =  blocks[1:] != blocks[:-1]

out = torch.cat([t[:1], t[:-1][mask],t[1:][mask], t[-1:]]).reshape(-1,2)
```

Output:

```
tensor([[ 3,  7],
        [20, 20],
        [31, 34]])
```